# pydev: package explorer disappears when file is openend

Tags: pydev

Silly question, but I don't know what to do:

My view in Eclipse pydev has changed;

Don't know what I did It used to be that the Pydev package explorer would appear on the left and then whatever file I selected would appear on the right, in the editor area. Instead, Pydev now opens a blank window.

I can make the  Pydev package explorer appear by selecting it from the little icon on the lower left. However, when I then click on a file, the file opens, but the explorer disappears. Very annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably made the package explorer work as a 'fast view'. You can do the following: Ctrl+F7 until you reach it (this keybinding should allow you to pass through the opened views), then alt+- (which should open the view menu) and deselect the 'fast view'.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I opened the Navigator, right-clicked the Navigator tab, and then clicked on Fast View, which was checked. Thanks.